# Почему в Kotlin, в параметрах аннотации, нельзя использовать Closure?

Tags: kotlin

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке.
При попытке скомпилировать что-то вроде этого:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class Argument(val name: String, val completion: () -> Collection<String>)
```

Получаю ошибку, которая говорит, что `() -> Collection<String>` - Invalid type of annotation member. Я так понимаю, что сделать то, что я хочу невозможно?

Comment: Скорее всего да, в аннотациях должны быть константы (в java, но вообще к этому обязывает контекст использования аннотаций вне зависимости от языка), поэтому требование "использовать только константы и выражения, которые может подсчитать компилятор", выглядит разумным.

Comment: Потому что параметры аннотации могут быть только таких типов: примитивы, String, Class, Enum, другая аннотация, массив из вышеперечисленного. Очевидно лямбда является объектом какого-то другого типа.

Comment: Действительно, в Java тоже нельзя использовать никакие объекты (кроме строк) в качестве параметра аннотаций.